# Why is header not getting smaller in mobile browser?

Tags: html, mobile, web

I have a media section in http://androdevlab.com/style.css that **should** apply to http://androdevlab.com when view in a mobile browser.
Specifically, the logo and the main title font should get a lot smaller, but they do not.

Wondering why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query tests `(max-width: 780px)`, which does not match many android phones, which usually report 800. Either change the media query to

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
```

or use `max-device-width`.

Alternatively, you can add the HTML element

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

to advise the mobile browser to use the actual resolution.